# Simple colour recognizing program

Tags: java, swing, colors, click, pattern-matching

I want to write a simple colour recognizing program in Java. I wish that this would run in the background, so I would be able to change windows. Then, when a certain, user specified colour appears on the screen, I want the cursor to navigate to, and click on where this colour appears.

The problem is I have no idea where to begin with a project of this nature. I am doing it purely for my own enjoyment/interview preparation and don't wish to use any outside APIs.

Can anyone offer any guidance on how I might begin with a project like this? I can then set about fleshing it out and asking more specific questions. What imports can I use here, how can I best recognize the colour on screen? How can I programmatically move and cause the cursor to click ?

Comment: What is the larger context of doing so?

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Vulcan - please don't suggest Programmers for this type of question. It's too broad for us there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very big question, however [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) can do this and it's written in Java and Python, you could just look at its code.